# CodeBlocks External Library Management

Tags: linker, codeblocks

I'm having some trouble installing libraries for use in Code::Blocks.  Specifically, the opencv library.  I would like to be able to store all of my libraries in a single file, and also be able to to include a header file from the library in any program by stating

```
#include "header.h"
```

rather than the much longer

```
#include "C:\ Programs \ bla \ bla \ bla \ Libraries \ mylib \ lib \ header.h"
```

Is this possible, or do I have to include a copy of the library in each of the programs that I want to use it in?

How should I configure my compiler and linker search directories to achieve this?  How should I configure my linker settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to, if all your header files are in one directory, include the directory in the global settings.  Every project will then look there for the file.

> code::blocks -> settings -> compiler settings -> global compiler settings -> compiler settings tab -> other options tab -> write "-I the/string/to/ your/directories" and -> OK

this makes all projects link to this directory.  If you place your headers there, you should be good to go

KR

Hewi

Comment: hey ivkid, in your original question you wrote: all my lib's in a single file, did you mean 'in a single directory'?